# Inserting text in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to send out some email that contains some macros that im replacing the text of..

But the problem is when i have more than one result i want to put into the text:

Hello [name], these people have written to you: [personname][personimage].

As long as its just one result it's ok.. but how to put in more results like this:

Hello [name], these people have written to you: [personname][personimage],[personname][personimage] ...etc.

These results i get from a while loop and have tried inserting a macro where its supposed to show up, but no luck..

Comment: Inside the while loop save it in a temporary variable and after the while loop is done, replace `[personname][personimage]` with your temporary variable

Comment: Even tho this question was hard to understand for some, it's still a real question. Read it several times and you will see what i ask for.

Mr.Niek van der steen answered perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your while loop store the data into an array, i.e.:

```
$myArray = array();
while(.. your condition) {
    $myArray[] = $theName;
}
```

Generate a string:

```
$myNameString = implode(',', $myArray);
```

And replace it within your text:

```
$myMessage = str_replace('[names]', $myNameString, $myMessage);
```

**Edit:** If you want multiple properties (in your example: name and image), just add it when you are putting it in the array. So instead of the $myArray[] = $theName, change it to:

```
    $myArray[] = $theName . ' ' . $theImage;
```

And the rest stays the same.